# JSP retrieving an XML sheet (Youtube)

Tags: xml, jsp, youtube

I am attempting to retrieve Youtube playlists to dsiplay on a JSP page, Youtube state you can retrieve a users playlist by sending a GET request to: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/userId/playlists?v=2

Which should then return a XML response, containing the playlist feed.

The issue I have though that only having had limited experience with JSP I am unsure how they mean send a GET request. How would I go about sending a GET request to retrieve this XML so I can then in turn isolate the tags I want to use?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@page import="java.net.*" %>
<%
  URL url;
  HttpURLConnection conn;
  BufferedReader rd;
  String line;
  String result = "";
  try {
     url = new URL(urlToRead);
     conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
     conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
     rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
     while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result += line;
     }
     rd.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
  System.out.println(result);
%>
```